# Why in some cases $0\alpha$ component of stress-energy tensor don't form 4-vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, covariance

In electrodynamics there is Poynting vector and energy density, which refer to $0\alpha $ components of stress-energy tensor, don't create 4-vector. Analogous situation with mass density and mass current density in general relativity. So why don't they form 4-vector (with what property is it connected)?

Comment: The $T_{0\alpha}$ components *never* form 4-vector. They are components of 2-nd rank tensor. $T_{0i}$ on the other hand form 3-vector with respect to transformation of only spatial coordinates.

Comment: @user23660: I meaned the integral representation of the momentum vector due of the stress-energy tensor components $0\alpha$.

Comment: I think that in case of EM field, the $T_{0\alpha}$ components do form a four-vector if there are no currents present, since $\partial^\alpha T_{0\alpha} = 0$ in every inertial frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I did not understand your question. However, referring to the stress-energy tensor, the four-vector you want is:

$$S_\nu = \int_{\Sigma_t} T_{0\nu} d^3x$$

where $\Sigma$ is the rest 3-space $x^0=t$ of Minkowski reference frame with coordinates $x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$. In view of the relation $\partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu}=0$ the definition of $S$ does not depend (1) on the used Minkonskian reference frame,(2) on  the value of $t$, (3) it defines a four-vector, and (4) it is conserved: $\partial_\mu S^\mu=0$.

All that is true if the region in spacetime  where $T \neq 0$ has compact intersection with every such $\Sigma_t$ (it is sufficient that it happens for one of them to be valid for all and for all reference frames). This condition can however be weakened.

The proofs of all I wrote easily arise from the (four-dimensional) divergence theorem.

**ADDED NOTE.** All the above discussion holds in Minkowski spacetime, in curved spacetime the picture becomes more complicated.  In a globally hyperbolic curved spacetime, a conserved current is obtained from a symmetric conserved stress energy tensor in the presence of a Killing vector $\xi$. Then $J^\mu:=\xi_\nu T^{\nu\mu}$ verifies $\nabla_\nu J^\nu=0$. In this case $$Q:= \int_\Sigma J^\mu n_\mu d\mu$$ is a conserved "charge" independent from the spacelike Cauchy surface $\Sigma$. Above $\mu$ is the natural measure induced on $\Sigma$ by the metric of the spacetime and $n$ the unit normal co-vector. The components of $S^\mu$ above have this structure, $\xi^{(\mu)}_\nu$ being the constant vector fields in Minkowski spacetime associated with a Minkowskian reference frame.

Comment: Yes, it's what I want.

Comment: But there is some little question: how exactly relation $\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu \nu}$ defines $S_{\nu}$ from your answer as 4-vector?

Comment: Consider two different Minkowskian reference frame $J$ and $J'$ connected by a certain Lorentz transformation, $\Lambda$, and define the corresponding four numbers $S_\mu$ and $S'_\alpha$ using the same tensor $T$ and integrating over the respective rest space. Then, the divergence theorem, the relation $\partial_\nu T^{\nu\rho}=0$, and the fact that $T$ is a tensor lead to $S'_\alpha = \Lambda_\alpha^\beta S_\beta$.

Comment: This definition does depend on the existence of a Minkowskian reference frame, however.  In full GR, care must be taken to define what that integral means.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : in GR we need to take the integral $ \int (-g)(T^{0 \nu} + \tau^{0 \nu})d^{3}x$, where $\tau$ is Landau-Lifshitz pseudotensor.

Comment: @AndrewMcAddams: and you need to project on the unit normal, rather than just aking the 0 component, and you need to invariantly define what you mean by a vector valued integral, since it's unclear to which tangent space it belongs.  Even when doing something like defining the ADM momentum, you end up with junk unless you project onto a tetrad connecting your physical geometry with a flat one on the surface where you're calculating the integral.  It's nontrivial.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer Sure! I interpreted all this question in Minkowski spacetime! In a globally hyperbolic curved spacetime you also need a Killing vector $\xi$. A conserved current is then $J^\mu := \xi_\nu T^{\nu\mu}$ (where the stress-energy tensor is supposed to be symmetric). In this case $\int_\Sigma J^\mu n_\mu \sqrt{\det{h}} d^3x$ is a conserved "charge" independent on the Cauchy surface $\Sigma$.

Comment: I added a corresponding note to my answer.

Comment: @V.Moretti : "...then, the divergence theorem, the relation $\partial_{\nu}T^{\nu \rho} =0$, and the fact that $T$ is a tensor lead to $S′_{\alpha}= \Lambda^{\beta}_{\alpha}S_{\beta}$...", but why do we need divergence theorem for showing that $S_{\alpha}$ is a 4-vector? It is possible only rewrite your definition in a form of
$$
S^{\nu} = \int_{t = const, all space} T^{\mu \nu}\Sigma_{\mu},
$$
which shows that $S^{\nu}$ refers to 4-vector.

Comment: @Andrew McAddams No, it does not work. You should first define a set of four components for each Minkowskian reference, integrating $T$ on the corresponding  rest frame. Next you have to prove that these sets of components transform with the right Lorentz transformations. This is by no means obvious and the conservation relation plays a fundamental role in proving it.

Comment: @V.Moretti : so I define
$$
S^{1}_{\nu} = \int T_{0 \nu}d\Sigma^{0}_{t= const}, \qquad S^{2}_{\mu} = \int T_{0 \mu}{'}d\Sigma{'}^{0}_{t = const},
$$
$$
T_{0 \mu}{'}d\Sigma^{0}{'} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\quad \beta}T_{0 \beta}d\Sigma^{0},
$$
and then 
$$
S^{2}_{\mu} = \int \Lambda_{\mu}^{\quad \nu}T_{0 \nu}d\Sigma^{0}_{t = const}.
$$
So where in the next step I must use the relation $\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu \nu} = 0$ for proving that $S_{\mu}$ is a 4-vector?

Comment: Excuse me, I want to understand this fully.

Comment: Though the identity $T' d\Sigma' = \Lambda T d\Sigma$ is correct about a point, say $p$, the final result is not because you are integrating on two different $3$-surfaces that are very far from each other as soon as you depart from $p$. To connect these integrals you have to use the divergence theorem and the conservation equation.